# Hide the subview from View in Storyboard in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a view controller in which i have used scrollview and under scroll view there are multiple subviews, Now i want one of the subview to hide initially when the page loads and it should be shown on a click of button, I have hide the subview from storyboard and from code also but the subview don't hides,i'm confuse why it is so, 
my code for hide is this,

```
 if (_fullView.tag==100) {
     [_fullView  setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: can you show some additional code

Answer (score 0):

**Objective C**

For Hiding try this :

```
[_fullView  setHidden:YES];
```

Using tag :

```
[[_fullView viewWithTag:100] setHidden:YES];
```

**Swift**

For Hiding :

```
_fullView.hidden = true
```

Using tag :

```
_fullView.viewWithTag(100)?.hidden = true
```

Comment: What is the difference between `.hidden` and `setHidden`

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan They are two different syntaxes for the same thing.

Comment: @the4kman OK.  Then question and answer has the same code what makes the difference here.

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan hidden=YES is identical to setHidden:YES The difference is, you are turning hidden to YES right away Whereas sethidden view disappears from its window and does not receive input events because it is set to be hidden. It remains in its superview’s list of subviews, however, and participates in autoresizing as usual.

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan - are you found the one mistake in answer, can you elaborate  `true` and `YES`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Even I am also zero in iOS. I am not aware of your question.

Comment: Bro it is not working the subview is still visible when i run the app. @DixitAkabari

Comment: it is not hidding subview. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Raheel set view tag and hide view using that tag.

Comment: BRO ITS not even hiding after setting up a tag. @DixitAkabari